# MpAndroidChart Customise Width and Height of Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart library for horizontal stacked bar chart inside a card view. I want to set the width of stacked bar chart to match with the card view. Is there any option to set barwidth to match parent?

Below is my code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">                                            

                            
                     <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
                                android:id="@+id/chart1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"                               
                                />

                        </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

To setdata:

```
    val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
    entries.add(BarEntry(0f,floatArrayOf(10f, 30f, 10f, 30f)))

    val set = BarDataSet(entries, "")
    val colors = ArrayList<Int>()
    colors.add(Color.GREEN)
    colors.add(Color.RED)
    colors.add(Color.GRAY)
    colors.add(Color.YELLOW)
    set.colors = colors

    val data = BarData(set)
    data.setDrawValues(false)
    data.isHighlightEnabled = false
    chart1.description.isEnabled = false
    chart1.data = data
    chart1.setDrawGridBackground(false)
    chart1.axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)
    chart1.axisLeft.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    chart1.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
    chart1.axisLeft.setDrawLabels(false)
    chart1.axisRight.setDrawGridLines(false)
    chart1.axisRight.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    chart1.axisRight.isEnabled = false
    chart1.axisRight.setDrawLabels(false)
    chart1.xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
    chart1.xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    chart1.xAxis.setDrawLabels(false)
    chart1.legend.isEnabled = false
    chart1.invalidate()
```

Can somebody tell how to set adjust width to match parent?

Seems like horizontal bar chart is surrounded with some space.
How to remove black border surrounding the horizontal bar chart?[image]

```
setViewPortOffsets(0f,0f,0f,0f)
setExtraOffsets(0f,0f,0f,0f) is not working
```

Comment: Please add your more snip of code so display card view and details.

Comment: @RatilalChopda Added more snipof code